# Error when parsing xml file using ElementTree (python)

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse an xml file I have (here is a sample):

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO>5000</DOCNO>
<PROFILE>_AN-CFBA3AF8FT</PROFILE>
<DATE>920602
</DATE>
<HEADLINE>
FT  02 JUN 92 / World Stock Markets (America): Growing optimism lifts Dow
Jones to record high
</HEADLINE>
<BYLINE>
   By PATRICK HARVERSON
</BYLINE>
<DATELINE>
   NEW YORK
</DATELINE>
<TEXT>
Wall Street

US STOCK MARKETS turned early weakness on higher bond yields into a
record-breaking performance yesterday as the Dow Jones Industrial Average
finished above 3,400 for the first time in its history, writes Patrick
Harverson in New York.
```

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('articles.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

But I keep getting this error in the terminal when I try to run my code/print the root tag:

```
File "xmlparse.py", line 3, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse('articles.xml')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1653, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1517, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 77, column 0
```

Anyone know why I'm getting this and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: A good first step is to ensure you're using well formed xml.

Comment: thanks @ColeTierney! How do I do that? Do you see any problems with the tags/format of the file I'm using?

Comment: If you have access to xmllint, try this: `xmllint --noout articles.xml`

Comment: @ColeTierney you are a lifesaver! the problem is that my xml file didnt have a root tag so i added one and now it works! thank you :))

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)